# Identify name of variable in Switch statement

Tags: powershell, switch-statement

I have the following code snippet:

```
$a = '1'
$b = ''

Switch ($a, $b) {
    {[string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_)} {
        Write-Host ("{0}: {1} is null." -f (Get-Date -Format s), $_)

        break
    }
    default {
        Write-Host ("{0}: {1} is not null." -f (Get-Date -Format s), $_)
    }
}
```

This Switch statement identifies variables without any assigned value. When I run it, I would like to be able to tell the user (or the log file) which variable is empty, is that possible?

The production code has many more variables and they are defined throughout the script by calling various APIs. I would prefer to avoid a whole bunch of If/else statements.

Comment: What use case? Looks like you're trying to reinvent parameter binding and validation.

Comment: The way that I would handle this is by using custom objects. One property would be the message that you want to show the user. The other would be the value. Then loop all of them and test. You could do something similar with a hashtable.

Comment: That's sorta what I'm leaning towards. I was thinking that I could do something like: $a = @{name = a; value = '1'}. Since some of the variables are actually arrays of objects, it makes getting them out later, difficult, but maybe that's okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than passing the variable *value* to the switch statement, you could pass the variable *name* instead, and use `Get-Variable -Value` to get the value in guards. This would look like

```
$a = '1'
$b = ''
$c = '3'
$d = '4'

Switch ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd') {
    {[string]::IsNullOrEmpty((Get-Variable -Value $_))} {
        Write-Host ("{0}: {1} is null." -f (Get-Date -Format s), $_)

        continue
    }
    default {
        Write-Host ("{0}: {1} is not null." -f (Get-Date -Format s), $_)
    }
}
```

Also - if you want the `switch` statement to loop over all of the variables, then you need to use `continue` instead of `break`. I've made this change in my example.

Comment: Populating hash tables works seems to work, but this is simpler. Thanks. Incidentally, I think I prefer to break out of the switch when I find a null variable, so the user can fix it. Because of the nature of the script, if one is null, it is likely that others will be and fixing the first one will fix the rest.